# cohomology ring of configuration spaces on $S^2$ and the projective plane

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory, cohomology, configuration-spaces

For a manifold $M$ and a positive integer $n$, the unordered configuration space $B(M,n)$ is the space consisting of all unordered collections of $n$ distinct points on $M$. Precisely,
$$
B(M,n)=\{(m_1,\cdots,m_n)\in M^n\mid m_i\neq m_j \text  { if } i\neq j\}/\Sigma_n
$$
where $\Sigma_n$ is the symmetric group on $n$-letters acting on $M^n$ by permuting the order of coordinates.

In the paper *[on the cohomology of configuration spaces on surfaces](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/68/2/477.full.pdf+html)*, the cell-structure of $B(S^2,n)$ is given in section 2.2. And the cell-structure of $B(\mathbb{R}P^2,n)$ is given in section 2.6.

**Question.**  I want to know the cohomology rings
$$
H^*(B(S^2,n);\mathbb{Z}_2)
$$
and
$$
H^*(B(\mathbb{R}P^2,n);\mathbb{Z}_2).
$$
How could these ring structures be derived from the cell-structures given in section 2.2 and section 2.6,  *[on the cohomology of configuration spaces on surfaces](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/68/2/477.full.pdf+html)*? How could I derive the explicit solution or find the explicit solution in any references?